# Convert enum member to corresponding text

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I have an enum as follows:

```
enum class MediaType() {
    AUDIO,
    VIDEO,
    ARTICLE;
}
```

I would like to add either a function or some property that allows an enum member to be converted to some corresponding text. For example:

```
var mediaType = MediaType.AUDIO
var text = mediaType.toText() // returns the string "MP3"

mediaType = MediaType.VIDEO
text = mediaType.toText() // returns the string "mpeg"
```

While I can add the toText function to the MediaType class, I am not sure how that function references the value it is set to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a property to the enum...

```
enum class MediaType(val text: String) {
    AUDIO("mp3"),
    VIDEO("mpeg"),
    ARTICLE("text");
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
println(MediaType.AUDIO.text)
```

If you'd like a `toText()` function rather than a property, that can be added as well, but probably isn't as idiomatic:

```
enum class MediaType(private val text: String) {
    AUDIO("mp3"),
    VIDEO("mpeg"),
    ARTICLE("text");

    fun toText(): String = text
}
```

Update:

Another way is to add an extension function and keep this logic outside the enum entirely:

```
fun MediaType.toText(): String = 
    when(this) {
       MediaType.AUDIO -> "mp3"
       MediaType.VIDEO -> "mpeg"
       MediaType.ARTICLE -> "text"
    }
```

Comment: But you're adding a parameter to the constructor. But I don't want a constructor. I want to just set a value like this: var mediaType = MediaType.AUDIO

Comment: @AndroidDev - See my update. You can do this with an extension function as well, which would leave your enum as-is and externalize the mapping of enum to String.

Comment: OK, I like your solution and will give you the selected solution although I just tried out my solution and actually like it better.

Comment: @AndroidDev why would the constructor be an issue? This is the most efficient (and arguably elegant) way of doing it, not just in Kotlin. You said you aren't sure how the "function references the value it is set to"; with this solution you don't _need_ that because it is a property of the enum itself.

Comment: Why would you add a constructor when you don't need it? See my solution above. It uses no constructor.

Comment: @AndroidDev Enums are objects and can have any internal state. Not having a constructor is not an indicator of better code; this is generally an accepted practice (see the [planet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) enum sample). Additionally manually switching on an enum when you have access to its internal state is prone to mistakes as it is very possible to leave out a constant, etc.

Comment: Also, enums already have a constructor, the JVM uses it to create singleton instances of each value. Even with adding a value to expose as a property, the JVM is calling the constructor - not you. You aren't adding a constructor that isn't already there by adding a property to it. I feel that the first solution I put is the most idiomatic (won't confuse other Kotlin developers).

Answer (score 1):

```
enum class MediaType() {
    AUDIO,
    VIDEO,
    ARTICLE;

    fun getMemberText() = when (this) {
        AUDIO -> "mp3"
        VIDEO -> "mpeg"
        else -> "text"
    }
}
```